# A fabric for all seasons

Tags: cryptic-clues

A fabric woven in a political figure.

> 5 letters

What am I ?

Comment: Trumphair burlap

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might be

> Linen, a fabric which is also an anagram of Lenin, a famous political figure.

Comment: Ah, yes, "woven" makes sense now. I kept thinking this as I read it but was like "No... Doesn't work." I thought "A fabric woven" was the definition. Well, it fits, maybe woven is part of both meaning here. =P

Comment: @SendersReagent The funny thing is that the fabric came to me when I read the title; everything else just kind of fell into place.

Answer (score 6):

I now wrongly  - apols too many letters - think it could be:

> Merino - a wool.  
>  The political figure - Thomas **More** the title has (A man) for all seasons  - and **in** and these are woven - anagram. 
>  Thanks for the comment - my previous thought 'moire' was dodgy with the 'i'

Comment: you are close, the answer is far simpler.